# Tikapatthana in English

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for a proper translation of the Tikapatthana into English which might be available online as a PDF.

Is it possible to point me to such reference. I am looking for the complete set.

Comment: Can you help me locate a PDF version of `Guide to Conditional Relations Part I by U Narada`

Answer (score 3):

Have a look on that.
Might be a first step.

http://www.dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?t=7990

Much Metta.
Thierry

Comment: Let me check it you. If you find the links please point me there.

Answer (score 1):

See [English translation of Tika Patthana](http://patthana.net/?page_id=36)

I found Tikapatthana on https://archive.org/search.php?, but i belive they are w/o translation?

[Vol 01: Tikapatthana of the Abhidhamma pitaka](https://archive.org/details/tikapatthanaofab01budduoft)

[Vol 02: Tikapatthana of the Abhidhamma pitaka](https://archive.org/details/tikapatthanaofab02budduoft)

[Vol 03: Tikapatthana of the Abhidhamma pitaka](https://archive.org/details/tikapatthanaofab03budduoft)

Comment: I can across the last 3 which are in Pali.

Comment: Any way thanks. Can you help me locate a PDF version of `Guide to Conditional Relations Part I by U Narada`

Comment: @Suminda Sirinath S. Dharmasena Is this link helpful? http://www.undv.org/vesak2012/iabudoc/07PyiPhyoKyawFINAL.pdf

Comment: Thanks. I have come across this before. [Paṭṭhāna - Guide to Conditional Relations, Part II](http://ftp.budaedu.org/ebooks/pdf/EN324.pdf), [Paṭṭhāna: 
Conditional Relations Part I](http://www.abhidhamma.com/Patthana1_Scan.pdf), [Paṭṭhāna: 
Conditional Relations Part II](http://www.abhidhamma.com/Patthana2_Scan.pdf), If you can find Paṭṭhāna - Guide to Conditional Relations, Part I this will be all that is traslated into English sofar as I belive. [This is licensed for non commercial use by PTS since 2013.](http://www.dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?t=7990#p330340)